# line-line intersection, determine if the line is inside a box (2d)

Tags: linear-algebra

Prefacing this with; I have not taken linear algebra as a class. I might need a little more guidance than normal.

**this is also a 2d scene**

**background**

I am a CS student and I decided to do a personal project on doing Ray-Casted light. I implemented [paul bourkes code solution](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/javascript.txt) for line-line intersection. I've mostly got it worked out for beams of light except for a bug.

depending on the rotation for these beams and how close they are to a boundary they'll go onto the other side. when the points are collected i get behavior like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HttBW.jpg) rightmost picture, when i want the leftmost.

When I first got the idea of doing this project from a video on YT, the person mentioned the line-line intersection formula had a way of getting 2 points, but did not elaborate.

**tl;dr**

how can I determine if a point is inside a box?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The box is always parallel to the axes?

Comment: @CyclotomicField the box and the set of rays can be any point in space, so not always. its also a 2d scene (ill add that to the question).